# Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 Nuget package is auto deleting in SSIS script task

Tags: ssis

I am trying to add Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 nuget package to SSIS script task. but when I close and reopen 
 the script task. I didn't see any packages in script task. Is there any other way to add that Nuget package to script task?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading the nuget package from google and adding that to the solution solved my issue.